# Swap integrated cpu graphics and real graphics card

Tags: graphics-card

I'm seeing that the idle power on most graphics cards is quite high, around 100w.

As I will mainly be using my computer for desktop applications, the high idle power consumption of the graphics card is actually going to cost quite a lot in a year.

So I'm thinking is there a way to turnoff the graphics card while being in Windows and use the integrated cpu graphics? Of course without opening the case, and preferable even without restarting Windows?

Comment: @downvoter why?

Comment: Might help to say what graphics cards are in use here.

Comment: And in what port do you want to plug in your monitor? Or do you want to switch them every time? It's a good question, but I think it's very hard to accomplish.

Comment: The asker could use a KVM switch to get around this issue. It's a sledgehammer but it would work... That or two monitors.

As for not using your PCI graphics card in Windows, can't you just disable it in the Device Manager after removing the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the system... it IS possible, but not recommended. You would need to choose 'integrated' graphics in your BIOS (requiring one restart) then, possibly, re-installing the drivers for the built in card (requiring a second restart.) My recommendation would be to leave it as is to avoid the headaches.